# vector iterator crashing my program when trying to call a funcition

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, sfml

I'm trying to make an object similar to search history and I have an issue with iterator to the search destination, which is crashing my program while initializing. Other problem is that when I'm trying to change some pointers (f.ex -> to * ) it can't find any functions

**.ccp**

```
History::History(std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Brick>>::iterator _itr)
:   itr(_itr)
{
    this->itr_text = (*itr)->getText(); // <--- this line is strange

    // some SFML
}

History::~History()
{

}
```

**.hpp**

```
class History
{
public:

    History(std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Brick>>::iterator _itr);
    ~History();

private:

    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Brick>>::iterator itr;
    std::string itr_text;

    /// some SFML
};
```

I'm planning to add some more iterator functions so I'd be thankful for you help

Comment: How do you *use* this `History` class? What is the iterator "pointing" at? Is the vector element a valid non-null pointer? Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

The `itr` is target elements of type 
 `std::unique_ptr<Brick>`. You can use :

```
this->itr_text = (*(*itr)).getText();
```

Or

```
this->itr_text = (*itr)->getText();
```

Comment: OK, it works. The issue was that I was initializing it before the actual object (whare iterator was) was created. Another stupid mistake on StackOverflow...